# What are sets that contain sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does the following set notation mean:

$$\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$$

What are the elements or subsets of this set?

Is this the same as $\{1,2\}$?

What about $$\{\{1\}\}$$
?

Comment: No, it is not. The elements of the set $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ are the sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$; the elements of the set $\{1,2\}$ are the integers $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What about the empty set?

Comment: What about it? It’s not an element of either of these sets, though of course it is a *subset* of both.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258891/is-the-set-1-emptyset-a-subset-of-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638560/why-can-a-1-element-set-be-a-member-of-another-set-but-not-a-subset-of-it

Answer (score 2):

$\big\{\{1\},\{2\}\big\}$ means the set that contains $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. It's in no way the same as $\{1,2\}$ which contains $1$ and $2$, and not $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the set $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. It is not equal to $\{1,2\}$.